# Need to create a separate mobile homepage. Does anyone know how?

Tags: magento2, extensions, redirect, mobile, home-page

I have Magento 2 store and I like the desktop theme but I do not like the mobile look of my homepage. How can I edit the mobile look of my homepage without altering the desktop version? At the moment if I alter the code both are changed. Is there any extension or method I can use to maybe create a separate mobile homepage and lead my customers there when they are on mobile devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create new theme by agent wise.

You can create new theme and call block using xml.

Hope it works for you

Comment: Any other way? I just need a mobile homepage. Is there anyways that I can just create a page and maybe redirect my homepage to the mobile version?

Comment: you can do something like you can find user agent of browser using php and make event for home page and rediect to home page to other page for mobile agent

Comment: how to detect :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15228937/php-check-if-the-page-run-on-mobile-or-desktop-browser

Comment: @SunilPatel, can you share some references about this.

Answer (score 0):

use the design rules (ADMIN - content - design - configuration) to detect the mobile devices

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using widgets and call the page based on the theme that is loading, however you still need to have 2 different themes. But with this method you can simply extend the theme and use user agents to show a different style, instead of creating a new theme with modifications.

This is also more flexible and easier to update if need be, else you need to amend the theme.

See sample setup below.

[image]